# Reading multiple csv files into SAS datasets

Tags: csv, macros, sas

I have the following csv files and I need to read them into SAS datasets.
Also, I need to assign column names. 
In addition, I need the column to be numberic but some columns have both number and character values.

folder aa:   abc1.csv, abc2.csv, abc3.csv,......
folder bb:  abc1.csv, abc2.csv, abc3.csv,......
folder cc:    abc1.csv, abc2.csv, abc3.csv,......

Comment: Do you have n number of folders which contain n number of csv files? Are you on Unix, Windows, Mainframe?

Comment: Yes, I have n number of folders which contain n number of csv files. I'm on Windows. I'm a newbie in SAS and really bothered by this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "need the column to be numeric"? Character values cannot be stored as numbers.

Comment: I need to treat character values as missing, so the column could be numeric. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in following way also.

1. Keep all your files in one folder.
2. Name all of them in a csv file with only one column.
3. Import the file (csv) with file names into SAS.
4. Create a macro to keep their name with "into" clause.

   ```
   proc sql;
   select name_list into :name separated by '*' from work.name;
   %let count2 = &sqlobs;
   quit;
   ```
5. Create a macro like below.

   ```
   %macro yy;
   %do i = 1 %to &count2;
   %let j = %scan(&name,&i,*);
   proc import out = &j datafile="folderwhereallcsvfilesarekept\&j..csv"
   dbms=csv replace;
   getnames = yes;
   run; 
   %end;
   %mend;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but it will get you started. You'll have to add an outer loop to go through the different directories you want to get files from.

```
/*List the files in a directory for use in a data step. This is written for Windows. Other operating systems will be slightly different. */
filename fnames pipe 'dir c:\temp\* /b';

/* Create a data set with one observation for each file name */
data fnames;
    infile fnames pad missover;
    input @1 filename $255.;
    n=_n_;
run;

/* Store the number of files in a macro variable "num" */
proc sql noprint; select count(filename) into :num; quit;

/* Create a macro to iterate over the filenames, read them in, and append to a data set. */
%macro doit;
    %do i=1 %to &num;

        proc sql noprint;
            select filename into :filename from fnames where n=&i;
        quit;

        data ds;
            infile &filename;
            input ...list of variable names...;
            ...other statements...;
        run;

        proc append data=ds base=final; run;
    %end;
%mend;

%doit;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, itzy! But I'm still trying to figure out. Really fresh to SAS.